# Aimeos: Minimum amount for small products

Tags: typo3

for small or cheap products a customer should often order only a larger amount of pieces. In this spirit, Magento shop offers the possibility for administrators or editors to specify the minimum amount of pieces specifically for every product.

In aimeos I have only found so far the possibilty to specify a global minimum amount for pieces in the basket which does not distinguish between the products.

For my project it is a mandatory feature to specify the minimum amount of pieces specifically for every single product. Have I overlooked something in aimeos? What is the best way to achieve this feature?

Many thanks in advance!

TYPO3 7.6.13, Aimeos web shop 16.10.1, PHP version 5.6.24-0+deb8u1, Linux

Answer (score 0):

In Aimeos, you can configure global values for the complete basket and for every product using the [ProductLimit basket plugin](https://aimeos.org/docs/User_Manual/Administration_Interface/Plugin_list#ProductLimit). For more information, have a look at the [Aimeos forum topic](https://aimeos.org/help/typo3-extension-f16/minimum-amount-for-small-products-t880.html)